# dplyr into data.table: filter > group by > count

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I usually work with `dplyr` but face a rather large data set and my approach is very slow. I basically need to filter a `df` group it by dates and count the occurrence within

sample data (turned already everything into `data.table`)

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.table(startmonth = seq(as.Date("2014-07-01"),as.Date("2014-11-01"),by="months"),
                 endmonth = seq(as.Date("2014-08-01"),as.Date("2014-12-01"),by="months")-1)


df2 <- data.table(id = sample(1:10, 5, replace = T),
                  start = sample(seq(as.Date("2014-07-01"),as.Date("2014-10-01"),by="days"),5),
                  end = df$startmonth + sample(10:90,5, replace = T)
)

#cross joining
res <- setkey(df2[,c(k=1,.SD)],k)[df[,c(k=1,.SD)],allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]
```

My `dplyr` approach works but is slow

```r
res %>% filter(start <=endmonth & end>= startmonth) %>% 
  group_by(startmonth,endmonth) %>% 
  summarise(countmonth=n())
```

My `data.table` knowledge is limited but I guess we would `setkeys()` on the date columns and something like `res[ , :=( COUNT = .N , IDX = 1:.N ) , by = startmonth, endmonth]` to get the counts by group but I'm not sure how the filter goes in there.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You might try `res[start <= endmonth & end >= startmonth, .N, by = .(startmonth, endmonth)]`

Comment: Corrected my sample and your approach works. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the counting inside the join:

```
df2[df, on=.(start <= endmonth, end >= startmonth), allow.cartesian=TRUE, .N, by=.EACHI]

        start        end N
1: 2014-07-31 2014-07-01 1
2: 2014-08-31 2014-08-01 4
3: 2014-09-30 2014-09-01 5
4: 2014-10-31 2014-10-01 3
5: 2014-11-30 2014-11-01 3
```

or add it as a new column in `df`:

```
df[, n := 
  df2[.SD, on=.(start <= endmonth, end >= startmonth), allow.cartesian=TRUE, .N, by=.EACHI]$N
]
```

*How it works.* The syntax is `x[i, on=, allow.cartesian=, j, by=.EACHI]`. Each row if `i` is used to look up values in `x`. The symbol `.EACHI` indicates that aggregation (`j=.N`) will be done for each row of `i`.